# Handling operational erros in node.js

Tags: node.js, error-handling

Let's say, hypothetically, we've got an array of objects that contains users and their IDs, like the following:

```
var Users = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Bob",
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "Alice",
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: "Pete",
}];
```

Now, if I had an asynchronous function that tried to get a user by their ID **using user input** (meaning that this function will be receiving their id from an untrusted source), it could look like the following:

```
function getUser(id) {
  var user = Users.filter(user => user.id === id);
  // working with input
  user.age = 12;
}
```

Now, of course this all is just an example.
However, if - in the above function - a non-valid or nonexistent id would be provided by the user and worked with (e.g. `user.age = 12`), an error would be thrown.

Since this error is not a programmatical error, nodejs shouldn't crash - but obviously, it still will. And with one function, this isn't a huge problem (a small `if` check wouldnt hurt) - but wrapping tens of hundreds of functions in try/catch blocks isn't optimal.

How can I handle operational errors en masse?

And last but not least, how would one go about this if the function was working with data asynchronously?

Comment: would an if check in this case provide the best speed/efficiency?

Comment: @jayf93 According to [this performance test](https://jsperf.com/try-catch-error-perf/3), a try/catch block is **much** slower than an if/else check. Note that this only is the case if an exception is actually thrown. If there is no exception thrown, the performance is about the same. The try/catch *might* even be faster since no additional checks are being performed, but im not an expert on that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I understood the whole point when you said `Node.js will crash`, but here are some pointers that it will not crash.

- You can check if provided id exists and is a string

  `if (id && typeof id === 'string')`
- You can check if received age from the async call exists and is a number

  `if (!err && user && user.age && typeof user.age === 'number')`

There are better ways of making such checks and guarding against these conditions.

[Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator): A node module to perform simple validations

[lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash): A node utility library (checkout isEmpty())

A *crash* (which is mostly an uncaught exception) happens when a non-permitted operation takes place, e.g. accessing a property of an undefined. There are other such cases as well. But this can happen in any language. Java can throw an NPE (NullPointerException) when you access a method of a null and *crash*.

Comment: Thats what i was referring to with "working with input", as - in the example given above - `user.age` is being accessed when it is undefined (since the user could enter practially anything resulting in the filter not returning anything). Thanks for your help though, I'll have a look at Validator. I  took lodash into consideration, but, unfortunately, it isn't an option for my use case.

Comment: Okay. Yeah, so the if condition I wrote will guarantee user.age is only accessed when user is present. It's better to check with `lodash.isEmpty()` for empty object or for a particular property `lodash.get(user, 'age.nested.nested')` to guard against such erroneous scenarios.

Comment: Okay, that seems good. I thought there might be a more sophisticated way of handling this, but it seems that conditionals will do the job. I also have looked into Promises, those can can catch programmatical errors aswell. They also will emit `unhandeledRejection` in the process if they're not caught, which is nice.

Comment: My suggestion is that don't obsess over `unhandledRejection`. Even if you don't use promises, you can listen for `process.on('uncaughtException')`. Most likely, after an unhandled rejection or an uncaught exception, your app is an undetermined state and it's best to restart it. You can log what happened before exiting the process, but technically, it does you no good.

Comment: Also, it doesn't have to be complicated conditionals, it just depends on the use case. If the JSON to be validated is a complex one, you can define a JSON schema for it and then validate against that. What matters is guarding against what can go wrong and you seem to be on the right track thinking ahead of the edge cases. cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much! I saw that `unhandledException` was a 'crude mechanism' to prevent an app from crashing, but letting it shut down gracefully sounds like a great idea :)